Spring-integration Supplier<?> object casting issue
I had an old application java 8 and springboot 1.8. I upgraded the project java 21 and springboot 3.3.5. Also I upgraded my spring-integration-java-dsl 1.2.3 to spring-integration-core 6.3.4 after that I am facing data type issue, Whenever I try to send a message a queue and consume back, that is converting just an byte[] instead Order object and naturally, I get casting exception. I have doubt about missing a configuration or wrong implementation of Supplier<>. Because I could get Order object directly with old version of dependency. Here are old and new implementation
application.yml  (old)
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost #127.0.0.1
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
  cloud:
    fail-fast: false
    stream:
      bindings:
        order-delay-output-channel:
          destination: orderDelayExchange
          producer:
            requiredGroups: orderDelayQueue
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          order-delay-output-channel:
            producer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              ttl: 30000

Output definition
public interface OrderProcessor
{
    @Output( "order-delay-output-channel")
    MessageChannel orderDelayOutputChannel();
} 

Integrationflow
    @Configuration
    @EnableBinding( OrderProcessor.class )
    public class IntegrationConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow orderDelayFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(ORDER_DELAY_CHANNEL)
                    .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".orderDelayFlow")
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "orderDelayFlow"))
                    .<OrderMessage>handle((orderMessage, headers) -> {
                        final Channel channel = (Channel) headers.get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL);
                        final Long deliveryTag = (Long) headers.get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG);
                        try {
                            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
                        } catch (final IOException exception) {
                            throw new MessagingException("ack failed", exception);
                        }
    
                        return orderMessage;
                    })

//when I send the message to order-delay-output-channel here 
//I can consume same message as an OrderMessage in another integration flow
                    .channel("order-delay-output-channel")
                    .get();
        }
    }

application.yml (new)
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: orderDelayOutputChannel;
    stream:
      defaultBinder: rabbit
      bindings:
        orderDelayOutputChannel-out-0: #order-delay-output-channel:
          destination: orderDelayExchange
          producer:
            requiredGroups: orderDelayQueue
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          orderDelayOutputChannel-out-0:
            producer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              ttl: 1000

Integrationflow
    @Configuration
    @EnableBinding( OrderProcessor.class )
    public class IntegrationConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow orderDelayFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(ORDER_DELAY_CHANNEL)
                    .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".orderDelayFlow")
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "orderDelayFlow"))
                    .<OrderMessage>handle((orderMessage, headers) -> {
                        final Channel channel = (Channel) headers.get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL);
                        final Long deliveryTag = (Long) headers.get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG);
                        try {
                            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
                        } catch (final IOException exception) {
                            throw new MessagingException("ack failed", exception);
                        }
    
                        return orderMessage;
                    })

//when I send the message to order-delay-output-channel here and
//I can consume same message as an byte[] in another integration flow
//Casting exception!
                    .channel("order-delay-output-channel")
                    .get();
        }
    }

Output definition
@Configuration
public class OrderProcess {

    @Bean("orderDelayOutputChannel")
    public Supplier<Message<OrderMessage>> orderDelayOutputChannel() {
        return () -> null;
    }
}

Other Implementation (Regarding your Consumer suggetion )
    public class OrderMessageProcessor {
//When I try to send a message with this implementation I get "No Dispatcher" error 
        @MessagingGateway
        public interface orderDelayOutputChannel extends Supplier<Message<OrderSend>> {}
    }


Sounds like you need to make yourself familiar with modern Spring Cloud Stream model: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/producing-and-consuming-messages.html. Doesn't looks like there is anything to do with Spring Integration (yet). That @EnableBinding is not there anymore. Please, also name Supplier as supplier: it is really not a channel. Right now your code is confusing by the names. Perhaps you might need to look into StreamBridge as well.

The code parts above "application.yml (new)" are belong to the old implementation. So I dont use EnableBinding anymore. My question is after @Output deprecated. How can I replace this code with new version of implementation
@Output( "order-delay-output-channel")
MessageChannel orderDelayOutputChannel();


When I checked the documentation, I can see similar implementation like this.
Only difference, I don't need to produce a message in supplier. I just transfer the exist one.
`public static class SupplierConfiguration {
@Bean
public Supplier stringSupplier() {
return () -> "Hello from Supplier";
}
}`

The supplier is producer of messages. Not sure what is your goal, but if you don't need it there for binding, you can be more specific what exactly you bind via spring.cloud.function.definition property.
